# Get the indices of min values for each row in a 2D np.array, if the min value satisfies a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique, where-clause

I've a 2D `np.array` with dimension `1000 (rows) x 12 (columns)`.

I need to get the indices of those values that are below `1.5`.
If a row contains more than one value that satisfies this condition, then I need to keep only the indices of the lowest.

I'd be quite happy with using 
`idx1,idx2=np.where(x < 1.5)`,
 but this sometimes returns several indices that are in the same rows.
I could of course loop over all repeated rows in `idx1` and keep only the indices whose values in `x` where are the lowest, but I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way.

Thanks

Comment: What if a row does not contain any value below 1.5? Do you just skip the row?

Comment: @jdehesa yes, then I’m no interested in that row. Only in the row-column indexes that are below 1.5, provided they are the lowest of their row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
# First index is all rows
idx1 = np.arange(len(x))
# Second index is minimum values
idx2 = np.argmin(m, axis=1)
# Filter rows where minimum is not below threshold
valid = x[idx1, idx2] < 1.5
idx1 = idx1[valid]
idx2 = idx2[valid]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a [numpy masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mask). Lets define the following random `ndarray`:

```
a = np.random.normal(1,2,(4,2))

print(a.round(2))
array([[ 1.41, -0.68],
       [-1.53,  2.74],
       [ 1.19,  2.66],
       [ 2.  ,  1.26]])
```

We can define a masked array with:

```
ma = np.ma.array(a, mask = a >= 1.5)

print(ma.round(2))
[[1.41 -0.68]
 [-1.53 --]
 [1.19 --]
 [-- 1.26]]
```

In order to deal with rows with no values bellow the threshold, you could do:

```
m = ma.mask.any(axis=1)
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Which will contain a `False` if there are no valid values along a given row.
And then take the `np.argmin` over the masked array to get the columns with the minimum values bellow 1.5:

```
np.argmin(ma, axis=1)[m]
# array([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

And for the rows you could do:

```
np.flatnonzero(m)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```